# Como popular um select com JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho uma tela de cadastro onde o usuario poderá adicionar ou não numeros de telefone. Estou adicionando campos para inserção do telefone dinamicamente, porem um desses campos é um select que irá trazer dados do banco de dados. Meu jquery está batendo no controller e está retornando a lista com os dados do banco, porém não está preenchendo o select, não sei onde está o erro. no console.log não trás nada.

Html

```
<button type="button" id="btnAddTelefone">Adicionar</button>
        <table id="tblTelefones">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>DDD</td>
                    <td>Numero</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
```

JQuery

```
$("#tblTelefones tbody").append("<tr>" +
                        "<td><select id='ddlTipoTelefone' name='ddlTipoTelefone'><option value>---Selecione um Tipo---</option></select></td>" +
                        "<td><input id='txtDDD'></td>" +
                        "<td><input id='txtNumero'></td>" +
                        "<td><input id='txtRamal'></td>" +
                        "<td class='bto'><button type='button' class='bt-salvar'>Salvar</button></td></tr>");

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "get",
                            url: "/Prestador/GetAllTipoAcessoTelefone",
                            data: { tipos: $("#ddlTipoTelefone").val() },
                            dataType: 'json',
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            success: function (obj) {

                                if (obj != null) {
                                    var data = obj.data;
                                    var selectbox = $('#ddlTipoTelefone');
                                    alert(data);
                                    //selectbox.find('option').remove();
                                    $.each(data, function (i, d) {
                                        $('<option>').val(d.TipoId).text(d.TipoNome).appendTo(selectbox);
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetAllTipoAcessoTelefone()
    {
        var lista = _commonService.GetAllTipoAcessoTelefonico()
            .Select(x => new { x.TipoId, x.TipoNome});

        return Json(lista, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Obs.: o alert(data) ali no meio aparece "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

Consegui apenas retirando o "obj" e deixando apenas "data".

deixo a solução para as proximas pessoas.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: "/Prestador/GetAllTipoAcessoTelefone",
  data: { tipos: $("#ddlTipoTelefone").val() },
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function (data) {
          var selectbox = $('#ddlTipoTelefone');
          $.each(data, function (i, d) {
              selectbox.append('<option value="' + d.TipoId+ '">' + d.TipoNome + '</option>');
          });
  } });
```

Comment: Ah, entao voce ja recebia o valor no objeto "data". Por isso nao funcionava. O loop estava recebendo o valor null e nao iniciava a iteracao.

Answer (score 0):

Uma das coisas que podem causar o erro é que todas as propriedades do objeto no json começam com inicial minuscula quando vem do controller,  conforme abaixo.
 Pra ver como está vindo fez um console.log(data) e vê como está vindo. 
 O restante parece correto.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: "/Prestador/GetAllTipoAcessoTelefone",
  data: { tipos: $("#ddlTipoTelefone").val() },
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function (data) {
          var selectbox = $('#ddlTipoTelefone');
          $.each(data, function (i, d) {
              selectbox.append('<option value="' + d.tipoId+ '">' + d.tipoNome + '</option>');
          });
  } });
```